# How can I make text stay on top right corner all the time in python?

Tags: python, text, position

**CHECK THE LINKS AND SEE FOR YOUR SELF HOPEFULLY YOU HAVE AN ANSWER (:**

[I want to make the CTRL - C to quit on the top right corner like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDT7n.png)

[But I get this instead the Quit message is in the middle instead of the being in the corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THuVr.png)

Answer (score 1):

I can't make anything from the images you provided. If you were to explain what do you need it for, OS you intend to run it on.. would be very helpful.

I made an overlay python app that would with a bit of work show text in either corner with or without a background.

The latter is an example made with wxPython, [link to the official site](https://www.wxpython.org/)

```
import wx

class FancyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        style = ( wx.CLIP_CHILDREN | wx.STAY_ON_TOP | wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR |
                  wx.NO_BORDER | wx.FRAME_SHAPED  )
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Fancy', style = style)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP, self.OnKeyDown)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouse)
        self.SetTransparent( 220 )
        self.Show(True)

    def OnKeyDown(self, event):
        """quit if user press q or Esc"""
        if event.GetKeyCode() == 27 or event.GetKeyCode() == ord('Q'): #27 is Esc
            self.Close(force=True)
        else:
            event.Skip()

    def OnMouse(self, event):
        """implement dragging"""
        if not event.Dragging():
            self._dragPos = None
            return
        self.CaptureMouse()
        if not self._dragPos:
            self._dragPos = event.GetPosition()
        else:
            pos = event.GetPosition()
            displacement = self._dragPos - pos
            self.SetPosition( self.GetPosition() - displacement )

app = wx.App()
f = FancyFrame()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I Intended to make the tool for both Unix And Windows Operating Systmes, I mean anything that supports python and specific libraries It's not something I need to do (the text) its just like more prettier UI.

Comment: @DarkestSurface wx works on macos linux distros and windows what are you trying to make?